# Ignore row based on a particular field under a column name

Tags: mysql

I have a very large csv file containing multiple fields such as : msg_id, transaction_type, flow_name, attribute_name, attribute_value. I need to load only those rows to database where attribute_name does not equal to say, "memo".

The snippet that I use to load the csv file goes something like this :

```
LOAD DATA infile 'c:/tmp/UserData.csv'
INTO TABLE UserData
FIELDS terminated by ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE rows where attribute_name="memo";
```

I need to fill up this "IGNORE" clause. How do I go about this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From my brief research into the MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement, it does not appear to be very flexible with what it can do.  That being said, would there be anything wrong with just reading in _all_ data and then deleting records with `attribute_name` = `"memo"` afterwards?

Comment: Extra: One reason why `LOAD DATA` isn't nearly as powerful as the operations MySQL exposes to a database is that in the case of a CSV file, the data hasn't been loaded yet and therefore isn't relational.

Comment: Tim, I need to ignore the rows while loading since this attribute name has hashed values containing all possible characters. I cannot load the records with such characters and hence need to ignore those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am updating logic but not verified by me, so can throw some syntax error but we can work on that-

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/UserData.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE UserData
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@id,field2,field3,....,fieldn) 
SET id = IF(attribute_name="memo", 1, @id);
```

Logic: we will set primary key value as 1 whereever attribute_name='memo' and then ignore duplicate row at the time of insertion as primary key 1 already exist so all rows will be skipped.